# What's wrong with this code? I try to create multiple arrays in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I try to create multiple arrays in a loop. I was told that the correct way to do this is by creating 2-dimentional arrays. So I made the following code, but it keep telling me eleArray[0] is undefined. anyone?  Thanks

```
    var eleArray = [];

       for(var i=0;i<rssArray;i++)
   {
       eleArray[i] = [];
   }

       eleArray[0][0] = "tester";

       alert(eleArray[0][0]);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java!

Comment: yeah sorry, just javascript, I will watch out next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `rssArray` is an array as the name implies, you need to loop based on the length:

```
for(var i=0;i<rssArray.length;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `rssArray` variable being initialized correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of your question.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhYRK/1/)

```
var array = [], length = 10, i;

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    array[i] = [];
}

array[0][0] = "Hello, World!";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = array[0][0];
```